# Aggregating rows across in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, aggregate

Sorry for the really noob SSRS question here. I am having trouble aggregating across my rows for my totals. Whenever I select my 3 columns that I need to aggregate (Rent,Exp,Other) = Total - It seems to sum down the instead of across.

I want to group my Total so I do not have 6 Rows of this Person with 6 different totals. I would just like 1 Grand total of the sums. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

[image: Example]
I would love this to be one consistent total for each unique Unit#

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using SUM() in the expression for each of the columns you want to total?   You need to be.

Comment: Yes, However my grand total doesn't seem to be adding the three together I am not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are grouping by Unit which would be correct but also by something else (Base Rent?).

I think you have an extra **Row Group** that you need to delete. Just delete the inside group, not the **related rows and columns**.

If that's not the issue, post a pic of your report in design view.

[image]